# c++ opening file with non-Latin name

Tags: c++, linux, qt, stl, fstream

I have such files.  I just want to open files with non-Latin names correctly.
I have no problems with files that have Latin names only with non-Latin names.

[image]

I use QDir for scanning directory and I hold names in QString, so it's held fine inside.

But there is a bottleneck with opening the file. 

It gets so that I don't want to use QFile, I can use only C++ streams (more preferred) or C files.

When I want to open file, I do so:

```
fstream stream(source.toStdString().c_str(),ios_base::in | ios_base::binary);
```

After that I check whether attempt was successful:

```
  if(!stream.is_open())
   { cout<<"file wasn't opened " <<source.toStdString().c_str())<<"\n";
     return false; // cout was redirected to file // just a notice
   }
```

I get in my log file: 
file wasn't opened  /home/sh/.mozilla/firefox/004_??????? - ????? - ?????.mp3

It doesn't work for any file with non-Latin name and it does work fine for every file with Latin names.

I understand that this problem can be jumped over using QFile.

But I wonder, is it possible to get it done without third-party  libraries or are there some another ways for solving it?

Thanks in advance for any tips.

Comment: `QString` has `toLocal8Bit` and `toUtf8`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Things are going wrong when you call `toStdString()` on your QString. It will convert the contents based on `QTextCodec::codecForCStrings()`, if it has been set, and latin-1 will be used otherwise. Latin-1 will collapse your non-latin characters to '?'s.

Using `source.toLocal8Bit().data()` or `source.toUtf8().data()` instead will likely do what you want, but failing that you'll need to deal with QTextCodecs to get the right 8-bit encoding.

Comment: Am I right in guessing that toLocal8Bit should be used on Windows and toUTf8 should be used on Linux?  It's so because on Windows local codepage may be used (but what if utf-16 is used?) and on  Linux  utf8 encoding is used by default/

Comment: @gekannt use toLocal8Bit() always. It's realy wrong to assume that linux "has utf8 by default". Even if it's true for most of distros it may be changed at any time so your code may fail.

Comment: Actually, I don't think Linux cares what encoding the filename has. To the kernel the name is just a set of bytes excluding ('/' and anything below < 0x20) that happens to be 8-bit clean and must be unique in that directory.

Comment: it's all very nice. But as I know, local encoding cannot support a few languages, e.g. it's impossible to contain in one local encoding German+Russian or Chinese+Hebrew. The problem is that a name of the file CAN possibly contain symbols from a few languages and I'll get mess if I just do tolocal8bit. So, if I just do tolocal8bit, I just ignore future problems that users will get.